# dangling if and macro

Tags: c++, macros, gcc-warning

I'm in the need to get rid of warnings, one of it is a -Wdangling-else. It notes a dangling if inside the following macro definition:

```
#define FOR_EACH_REF(var, container) \
    if(bool _cont = true) \
      for(our::remove_reference<decltype(container)>::type::iterator _it = (container).begin(); _it != (container).end() && _cont; ++_it) \
        if((_cont = false)) {} else \
          for(our::remove_reference<decltype(container)>::type::value_type& var = *_it; !_cont; _cont = true)
```

I must admit, I do not really get into this macro and thus do not know, how to resolve this warning.

Could anyone help me with an explanation on how to avoid the dangling else?

Comment: `#define FOR_EACH_REF(var, container) for (auto& var : container)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 jepp, that is the point, no auto variables and new stuff, need old compiler support.

Comment: @OliverFriedrich `auto` is as old as `decltype`...

Comment: ^That, what version are you really aiming for?

Comment: @passer need support for an old armv5 compiler and windows (though the last one is really the lesser problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might reverse the condition to avoid to have empty if-block and so problematic `else`:

```
#define FOR_EACH_REF(var, container) \
    if (bool _cont = true) \
      for(our::remove_reference<decltype(container)>::type::iterator _it = (container).begin(); _it != (container).end() && _cont; ++_it) \
        if(!(_cont = false)) \
          for(our::remove_reference<decltype(container)>::type::value_type& var = *_it; !_cont; _cont = true)
```

Since C++11, it would even be easy to write:

```
#define FOR_EACH_REF(var, container) for (auto& var : container)
```

Comment: surprisingly easy that did it. I interpreted the warning on the wrong line, obviously. Thank you.

Comment: This macro, like the OP's version, will not work before C++11 without the help of non-standard compiler extensions.  `decltype` was introduced in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

> how to avoid the dangling else?

The easiest (and not recommended) option is disabling the warning in the compiler with `-Wno-dangling-else`.

The real solution is to add braces around the `if`/`else` branches:

```
#define FOR_EACH_REF(var, container) \
    if(bool _cont = true) { \
    for(/* ... */) \
        if((_cont = false)) {} else { \
        for(/* ... */)

#define FOR_EACH_REF_END }}
```

Usage:

```
FOR_EACH_REF(foo, bar) 
{ 

}
FOR_EACH_REF_END
```

---

If you want to iterate over a range, C++11 provides language syntax for that, which should be used instead of this abominable macro:

```
for(const auto& var : container) { }
```